# Mesh not displayed when launching with ROS

Tags: gazebo, mesh, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I created a cube with a texture in Blender, exported it as .obj and converted it with meshlab to .dae. I included the File in the world and works fine if I run it with gazebo . But if I try running it with ROS, where i basically just included that world, the Object is not visible. ROS outputs also an errormessage, but I don't know if it's related to Problem.

Versions:
Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo, Gazebo 2.2.3

Only Gazebo:
[image: only gazebo]

With Ros:
[image: image description]

Errormessage:[image: image description]

If you need any further information, just let me know what you need.
Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14988/mesh-not-displayed-when-launching-with-ros/) by [lelmac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2953/lelmac/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I fixed it by placing the mesh and the texture into the .gazebo folder and using absolute paths to it.

---

Originally posted by [lelmac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2953/lelmac/) with karma: 1 on 2016-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0